# Why does showing off your powers expose you in the Hero Certification Program in the Super Powereds novels?

Tags: powers, super-powereds

In the world of the [*Super Powereds*](https://www.drewhayesnovels.com/superpowereds/) novels by Drew Hayes, there are many people with powers. Some ("supers") can control them, and some ("powereds") cannot. They can go about their lives with these abilities, but some opt to attempt a Hero Certification Program, or HCP, at various universities. However, the rules state that if a student in the HCP gets outed by a non-HCP student at the university, the super will get kicked out of the HCP.

There's a fair amount of angst among the HCP students that they should not let anyone outside the program know they have powers. It gets to the point where students might risk their lives rather than expose their powers. But having powers doesn't actually mean a student is in the HCP. So why would a student be quite so careful about hiding their powers, instead of just pretending to be a regular student who happens to have powers?

Comment: "Hey look, that girl just dropped a house on my friend, I'm going to go complain to faculty" Basically, non-HCP don't know and will complain anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Powers are unique, and enemies are resourceful.

> "While there are vast amounts of similar abilities in the world, each Super is unique."
>
> — Dean Blaine / Zero, [*Super-Powereds: Year 4*, chapter 59](http://www.drewhayesnovels.com/spy4/59)

> "You only have to keep it secret as a student; after that it’s a choice."
>
> — Owen Daniels / Titan, *Corpies*, Epilogue

Since no two Supers have identical power sets, an HCP student using powers while unmasked could potentially permanently compromise his or her future secret identity.  Students who have not successfully completed the full four-year HCP program do not have the education and experience to fully understand how an early unmasking could limit their personal lives and career options.

For example, in Year 4, students audition for their two-year internships.  An established Hero --- with a rogues' gallery of enemies willing to exploit any weakness --- would most likely not be willing to compromise his or her effectiveness, nor to endanger the family of an intern whose identity was no longer secret.

A publicly-suspected HCP student would also draw attention to all of his or her associates.  On an HCP campus, chances would be high for at least some of those associates to be fellow HCP students.